# change layer depth in JLayeredPane java

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I'm using JLayeredPane  to draw several layers, each layer has different depth 
my question is: 
How can i change the layer depth at run time?
i need to change the depth of `previewMap` from 0 to 1, and the depth of `mapControlPanel` from 1 to 0

[image]

Comment: To change a component depth dynamically, use the setLayer method.

Comment: JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane ();
JPanel previewMap = new JPanel();
JPanel mapControlPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
layeredPane.add(previewMap, Integer.valueOf(0));
layeredPane.add(mapControlPanel, Integer.valueOf(1));

Comment: soorry for not fomatted code =, but there is a problem with the website

Comment: i want to keep components in it's layers, and change the layers depth

Comment: [How to use Layered Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: i want to use it exactly as Adobe flash layer system
when user change the layer order, the depth of this layer is changed and consequently the components in this layer

Comment: i added picture for explanation 
thank you very much